# Использование нескольких таблиц через одну модель ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть модель, в которой задана таблица, с которой будет взаимодействовать приложение.

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    
    namespace Web_API1
    {
        
        [Table("passports")]
        public class Passport
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string Series { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Могу ли я таким образом использовать несколько таблиц? Использую PostgreSQL через Npgsql.

Comment: что такое `использовать несколько таблиц`?

Comment: В базе данных есть две таблицы с одинаковыми столбцами. Здесь, прямо в файле с моделью, я указал, из какой таблицы брать данные. Но мне так же нужно будет добавлять и считывать данные из другой таблицы с такой же структурой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372892/312041 ?

Comment: Да, полностью решило проблему, спасибо, осталось закрыть вопрос